# Python dict with tuples index to indented dict

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am analysing a facebook conversation and I want to know how many messages each person sends for each hour of the day. Using Pandas, I did `data['n_msg_by_hour'] = df.groupby(['author', df['date'].dt.hour])['_id'].count()`. The series object returned has this wanted form:

```
Djézeune        0       4866
                1       4549
                2       4463
                3       3841
                4       2560
                5       1029
                6        396
                7        239
                8         76
                9         56
                10        40
                11        88
                12       340
                13       685
                14      1253
                15      1712
                16      2224
                17      2650
                18      2439
                19      2951
                20      3347
                21      3575
                22      4696
                23      4741
Vinssan         0        108
                1        129
                2         84
                3         72
                4          8
                5         17
                6          4
                7          1
                8          1
                9          1
                11         4
                12        26
                13        37
                14        81
                15       114
                16        92
                17       123
                18        83
                19        95
                20        58
                21       112
                22        87
                23       109
Name: _id, dtype: int64
```

However, when I do `data['n_msg_by_hour'].to_dict()` I have a dict with tuple as keys like this:

```
{
('Djézeune', 0):4866,
('Djézeune', 1):4549,
('Djézeune', 10):40,
('Djézeune', 11):88,
('Djézeune', 12):340,
('Djézeune', 13):685,
('Djézeune', 14):1253,
...
('Vinssan', 0):108,
('Vinssan', 1):129,
('Vinssan', 10):0,
('Vinssan', 11):4,
('Vinssan', 12):26,
('Vinssan', 13):37,
('Vinssan', 14):81,
}
```

But I would like to have an indented dict to put it afterwards in a json

```
{
'Djézeune':{0:4866, 1:4549, 10:40, 11:88, 12:340, 13:685, 14:1253 ...},
'Vinssan':{0:108, 1:129, 10:0, 11:4, 12:26, 13:37, 14:81 ...}
}
```

Is there an easy way to do it with the `level` option of `groupby` or a function from `pandas` like `MultiIndex` I could use instead of iterating over my dict keys?

Each row in my DataFrame looks like this:

```
{_id : 5d9e716e5a20777bdb1b22f5,
author : "Djézeune",
timestamp : 1568670904454,
date : 2019-09-16T17:55:04.000+00:00,
type : "Generic",
content : "Hello"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to achieve by grouping by the first level of the index and iterating over the resulting `Series`es:

```
In [320]: s = pd.Series(np.random.random(48), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["DJ", "Vin"], range(24)]))

In [321]: d = {k: v.droplevel(0).to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}

In [322]: d
Out[322]:
{'DJ': {0: 0.8731657595223525,
  1: 0.6806768452816228,
  2: 0.6376297431476246,
  ...
  23: 0.9995968607512785},
 'Vin': {0: 0.19255930821536904,
  1: 0.944802244484905,
  2: 0.1171672201795304,
  ...
  23: 0.7387196132363647}}
```